# I can't get the answer right to this first-order condition derivative

Tags: partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier, economics

Came across a paper where the authors use LaGrange/shadow variable to solve for an electricity pricing problem.
The objective function: $$\sum_{i\in L} v^i(p_{L},w_L^i)+\sum_{i\in H} v^i(p_{H},w_H^i)$$
*The $v^i$ s are indirect utility functions
The constraint:$$(p_L-c)[n_Hq+\sum_{i\in L} e^i(p_L,w_L^i)]+(p_H-c)[\sum_{i\in H}e^i(p_H,w_H^i)]=F$$
*F is the fixed cost. we treat it as zero here.
The paper went on to generate the first order conditions in regard to $p_H$, $p_L$, and q.
$p_H$ stands for the higher block price in an increasing block price model, $p_L$ stands for the lower block price. q is the quantity threshold that separate the blocks.
$ $
I did not get what the paper generated at all. Let me screenshot the three conditions below:
I think I did something wrong here, I never get what the paper did for $\partial F/ \partial q$ and the partials for the other two variables. 
[the constraint equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdYIy.png)
[the budget constraint and more detailed problem setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFRR3.png)
$ $
Can anyone be so kind and walk me through step by step?[the paper's solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJHSA.png)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I never get what the paper did for  $\partial F/\partial q$". As you say in your question "F is the fixed cost", so $\partial F/\partial q=0$ (even if we do not "treat it as zero here").

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a link to the paper (or better: update your question to provide all the necessary information so that the screenshots are not necessary) The screenshots are very hard to read and the notation is not all explained in the screenshots. The notation in your question also slightly differs from that in the screenshots.